# bash insert a new line before specific pattern

Tags: string, macos, bash, newline

I have a csv file with the following contents:

```
"user1","track1","player1" "user1","track2","player2" "user2","track1","player1""user2","track2","player2".....
```

I need to insert a new line before this pattern: `"user`.
Actually at the beginning I replaced every space with a new line with this command

```
awk -v RS=" " '{print}' myfile >output.csv
```

but then I found that at some points in my file, there is not space before some users and when I impoted into the DB the values of columns were swapped at those points... :|. So I was wondering if someone knows how could I insert a new line before specific set of characters to avoid that problem..

Thanks,

Comment: Is the entire file just one line?

Comment: @dawg: yes, its a very long 1 line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *GNU* `sed` you can try this:

```
sed -r 's/(.)("user)/\1\n\2/g' myfile >output.csv
```

With BSD/OSX `sed` (wich doesn't support escape sequence `\n` in the replacement string, using an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) string), use:

```
sed -E $'s/(.)("user)/\\1\\\n\\2/g' myfile >output.csv

# Alternative, with the ANSI C-quoted quoted string spliced in only where needed.
sed -E 's/(.)("user)/\1\'$'\n''\2/g' myfile >output.csv
```

With a strictly POSIX-compliant `sed`, use a literal newline instead of escape sequence `\n`:

```
sed 's/\(.\)\("user\)/\1\
\2/g' myfile >output.csv
```

Note that with your sample input some lines will have a trailing space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the first one inserted n instead of new line:|

Comment: That means you need to use the 2nd command form; are you on OSX?

Comment: yes, .. should I user the the second form in 2 steps?

Comment: See my update - I've added a single-line form that works on OSX; the last form also would work as-is - it just needs to span 2 lines.

Comment: On OS X you can also do `sed -E 's/(\"user[0-9]+\")/\'$'\n\\1/g'`

Comment: @dawg: If you only use the ANSI C-quoted string for _part_ of the script - which is definitely worth considering to avoid the potentially confusing _double_ escaping - I suggest limiting it to `$'\n'`, spliced in between two regular single-quoted halves - see my update. As an aside: matching `[0-9]+` is not a requirement, and your command also inserts an `\n` before the first `"user`.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`

```
awk  '{gsub(/"user/,"\n\"user"); print}' file
```

That will have a leading CR in it if the file starts with `"user`

If you want to get rid of that, you can do:

```
awk  '{gsub(/"user/,"\n\"user"); sub(/^\n/,""); print}' file
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. also your answer worked for me.. sorry I couldn't accept two answers :|